# How to Resample and have value counts with value as new column header and counts as its value

Tags: python, pandas

After resampling i want the unique values to be a new column header and its count as the value.

i have tried

```
new_df.set_index('time').resample('60T').apply(lambda x: list(x))
```

```
        time            camera_id
0   2019-05-06 12:00:00 [cam02]
1   2019-05-06 13:00:00 []
2   2019-05-06 14:00:00 [cam01, cam01, cam01, cam02, cam02, cam02, cam...
3   2019-05-06 15:00:00 [cam02, cam02, cam02, cam02, cam02, cam02, cam...
```

i want it like this

```
    time                cam01  cam02  cam03
0   2019-05-06 12:00:00 0         1     0
1   2019-05-06 13:00:00 0         0     0
2   2019-05-06 14:00:00 0         10    0
3   2019-05-06 15:00:00 1         5     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) before `resample` with [`Resampler.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.size.html) and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (new_df.set_index('time')
            .groupby('camera_id')
            .resample('60T')
            .size()
            .unstack(0, fill_value=0))
print (df)
camera_id            cam01  cam02  cam03
time                                    
2019-05-06 12:00:00      0      1      0
2019-05-06 13:00:00      0      0      0
2019-05-06 14:00:00      0     10      0
2019-05-06 15:00:00      1      5      1
```

Comment: i got TypeError: 'TimeGrouper' object is not callable .what if i groupby camera_id and time_series together